# ConnectionException from SmackException

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to write `messaging` application in which the app and server are in same apk file. the app sends message directly to `GCM` and from there to the apk installed on the device. when a call when `connect()` function is called for `XMPPTCPConnection`, it throws and exception `org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException`.
Below is the code which connects to GCM server

```
package com.GcmServerImplementation;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketInterceptor;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException.NotConnectedException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.PacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.PacketExtensionProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

/**
 * Sample Smack implementation of a client for GCM Cloud Connection Server. This
 * code can be run as a standalone CCS client.
 *
 * <p>For illustration purposes only.
 */
public class SmackCcsClient 
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SmackCcsClient");

private static final String GCM_SERVER = "gcm.googleapis.com";
private static final int GCM_PORT = 5235;

private static final String GCM_ELEMENT_NAME = "gcm";
private static final String GCM_NAMESPACE = "google:mobile:data";
private static final long senderId = 561560678360L;
private static final String password = "AIzaSyDKiIbL8Dn_2Lxci_kN3shU9i_ORseJF08";
private XMPPConnection connection;

/**
 * Indicates whether the connection is in draining state, which means that it
 * will not accept any new downstream messages.
 */
protected volatile boolean connectionDraining = false;

static 
{
    ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE,
        new PacketExtensionProvider() {
            @Override
            public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser) throws
                    Exception {
                String json = parser.nextText();
                return new GcmPacketExtension(json);
            }
        });
}



/*public SmackCcsClient() throws Exception 
    {
        SmackCcsClient ccsClient = new SmackCcsClient();

        ccsClient.connect(senderId, password);
// Send a sample hello downstream message to a device.
        String toRegId ="APA91bHAxquB3kjk-VV5FY_dxgm1qYege0aepIZ7ZQ7rc8fPReiSPNCf5b7t5Hu4neKI7pf2Pl6P6D6M7zH17E9GJZmUV8Cu1BojlTTQQfM1IiZPomsxlyInZaZ5Qk6AP9qzAGz2oVVkC5zUZ5U2noERNxkUBqjfrw";
        String messageId = ccsClient.nextMessageId();
        Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<String, String>();
        payload.put("Hello", "World");
        payload.put("CCS", "Dummy Message");
        payload.put("EmbeddedMessageId", messageId);
        String collapseKey = "sample";
        Long timeToLive = 10000L;
        String message = createJsonMessage(toRegId, messageId, payload, collapseKey, timeToLive, true);

        ccsClient.sendDownstreamMessage(message);
    }*/
/**
 * Sends a downstream message to GCM.
 *
 * @return true if the message has been successfully sent.
 */
public boolean sendDownstreamMessage(String jsonRequest) throws
        NotConnectedException {
    if (!connectionDraining) {
        send(jsonRequest);
        return true;
    }
    logger.info("Dropping downstream message since the connection is draining");
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns a random message id to uniquely identify a message.
 *
 * <p>Note: This is generated by a pseudo random number generator for
 * illustration purpose, and is not guaranteed to be unique.
 */
public String nextMessageId() {
    return "m-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}

/**
 * Sends a packet with contents provided.
 */
protected void send(String jsonRequest) throws NotConnectedException {
    Packet request = new GcmPacketExtension(jsonRequest).toPacket();
    connection.sendPacket(request);
}

/**
 * Handles an upstream data message from a device application.
 *
 * <p>This sample echo server sends an echo message back to the device.
 * Subclasses should override this method to properly process upstream messages.
 */
protected void handleUpstreamMessage(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
    // PackageName of the application that sent this message.
String category = (String) jsonObject.get("category");
String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, String> payload = (Map<String, String>) jsonObject.get("data");
payload.put("ECHO", "Application: " + category);

// Send an ECHO response back
String echo = createJsonMessage(from, nextMessageId(), payload,
        "echo:CollapseKey", null, false);

try {
    sendDownstreamMessage(echo);
} catch (NotConnectedException e) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Not connected anymore, echo message is not sent", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Handles an ACK.
 *
 * <p>Logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it to
 * properly handle ACKs.
 */
protected void handleAckReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
    String messageId = (String) jsonObject.get("message_id");
String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleAckReceipt() from: " + from + ", messageId: " + messageId);
}

/**
 * Handles a NACK.
 *
 * <p>Logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it to
 * properly handle NACKs.
 */
protected void handleNackReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
    String messageId = (String) jsonObject.get("message_id");
String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleNackReceipt() from: " + from + ", messageId: " + messageId);
}

protected void handleControlMessage(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleControlMessage(): " + jsonObject);
String controlType = (String) jsonObject.get("control_type");
if ("CONNECTION_DRAINING".equals(controlType)) {
    connectionDraining = true;
} else {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Unrecognized control type: %s. This could"+
   " happen if new features are " + "added to the CCS protocol.", controlType);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a JSON encoded GCM message.
 *
 * @param to RegistrationId of the target device (Required).
 * @param messageId Unique messageId for which CCS will send an
 *         "ack/nack" (Required).
 * @param payload Message content intended for the application. (Optional).
 * @param collapseKey GCM collapse_key parameter (Optional).
 * @param timeToLive GCM time_to_live parameter (Optional).
 * @param delayWhileIdle GCM delay_while_idle parameter (Optional).
 * @return JSON encoded GCM message.
 */
public static String createJsonMessage(String to, String messageId,
        Map<String, String> payload, String collapseKey, Long timeToLive,
        Boolean delayWhileIdle) {
    Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    message.put("to", to);
if (collapseKey != null) {
    message.put("collapse_key", collapseKey);
}
if (timeToLive != null) {
    message.put("time_to_live", timeToLive);
}
if (delayWhileIdle != null && delayWhileIdle) {
    message.put("delay_while_idle", true);
    }
  message.put("message_id", messageId);
  message.put("data", payload);
  return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
}

/**
 * Creates a JSON encoded ACK message for an upstream message received
 * from an application.
 *
 * @param to RegistrationId of the device who sent the upstream message.
 * @param messageId messageId of the upstream message to be acknowledged to CCS.
 * @return JSON encoded ack.
 */
protected static String createJsonAck(String to, String messageId) {
Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
message.put("message_type", "ack");
message.put("to", to);
message.put("message_id", messageId);
    return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
}

/**
 * Connects to GCM Cloud Connection Server using the supplied credentials.
 *
 * @param senderId Your GCM project number
 * @param apiKey API Key of your project
 */
public void connect(long senderId, String apiKey) throws XMPPException, IOException, SmackException 
{
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(GCM_SERVER, GCM_PORT);
    config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
    config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
    config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
    config.setSendPresence(false);
    config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();

    connection.addConnectionListener(new LoggingConnectionListener());

    // Handle incoming packets
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet)
    {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Received: " + packet.toXML());
Message incomingMessage = (Message) packet;
GcmPacketExtension gcmPacket = (GcmPacketExtension) incomingMessage.getExtension(GCM_NAMESPACE);
String json = gcmPacket.getJson();
try 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> jsonObject = (Map<String, Object>) JSONValue.parseWithException(json);

    // present for "ack"/"nack", null otherwise
    Object messageType = jsonObject.get("message_type");

    if (messageType == null) {
        // Normal upstream data message
        handleUpstreamMessage(jsonObject);

        // Send ACK to CCS
        String messageId = (String) jsonObject.get("message_id");
        String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
        String ack = createJsonAck(from, messageId);
        send(ack);
    }
    else if ("ack".equals(messageType.toString())) 
    {     // Process Ack
          handleAckReceipt(jsonObject);
    }
    else if ("nack".equals(messageType.toString())) 
    {     // Process Nack
          handleNackReceipt(jsonObject);
    }
    else if ("control".equals(messageType.toString())) 
    {     // Process control message
          handleControlMessage(jsonObject);
    }
    else
    {
          logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Unrecognized message type (%s)", messageType.toString());
    }
}
catch (ParseException e) 
{
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing JSON " + json, e);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to process packet", e);
        }
    }
}, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

// Log all outgoing packets
connection.addPacketInterceptor(new PacketInterceptor()
{
    @Override
    public void interceptPacket(Packet packet) 
    {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sent: {0}", packet.toXML());
    }
}, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

connection.login(senderId + "@" + GCM_SERVER, apiKey);
    }

   /* public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        SmackCcsClient ccsClient = new SmackCcsClient();

        ccsClient.connect(senderId, password);
// Send a sample hello downstream message to a device.
        String toRegId ="APA91bHAxquB3kjk-VV5FY_dxgm1qYege0aepIZ7ZQ7rc8fPReiSPNCf5b7t5Hu4neKI7pf2Pl6P6D6M7zH17E9GJZmUV8Cu1BojlTTQQfM1IiZPomsxlyInZaZ5Qk6AP9qzAGz2oVVkC5zUZ5U2noERNxkUBqjfrw";
        String messageId = ccsClient.nextMessageId();
        Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<String, String>();
        payload.put("Hello", "World");
        payload.put("CCS", "Dummy Message");
        payload.put("EmbeddedMessageId", messageId);
        String collapseKey = "sample";
        Long timeToLive = 10000L;
        String message = createJsonMessage(toRegId, messageId, payload, collapseKey, timeToLive, true);

        ccsClient.sendDownstreamMessage(message);
    }*/

public static void sendMessage() throws Exception
{
    SmackCcsClient ccsClient = new SmackCcsClient();

    ccsClient.connect(senderId, password);
// Send a sample hello downstream message to a device.
String toRegId ="APA91bHAxquB3kjk-VV5FY_dxgm1qYege0aepIZ7ZQ7rc8fPReiSPNCf5b7t5Hu4neKI7pf2Pl6P6D6M7zH17E9GJZmUV8Cu1BojlTTQQfM1IiZPomsxlyInZaZ5Qk6AP9qzAGz2oVVkC5zUZ5U2noERNxkUBqjfrw";
String messageId = ccsClient.nextMessageId();
Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<String, String>();
payload.put("Hello", "World");
payload.put("CCS", "Dummy Message");
payload.put("EmbeddedMessageId", messageId);
String collapseKey = "sample";
    Long timeToLive = 10000L;
    String message = createJsonMessage(toRegId, messageId, payload, collapseKey, timeToLive, true);

    ccsClient.sendDownstreamMessage(message);
}
/**
 * XMPP Packet Extension for GCM Cloud Connection Server.
 */
private static final class GcmPacketExtension extends DefaultPacketExtension {

    private final String json;

    public GcmPacketExtension(String json) {
        super(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE);
        this.json = json;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    public String toXML() {
        return String.format("<%s xmlns=\"%s\">%s</%s>",
                GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE,
                StringUtils.escapeForXML(json), GCM_ELEMENT_NAME);
    }

    public Packet toPacket() {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.addExtension(this);
        return message;
    }
}

private static final class LoggingConnectionListener
        implements ConnectionListener {

    @Override
    public void connected(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {
        logger.info("Connected.");
}

@Override
public void authenticated(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {
    logger.info("Authenticated.");
}

@Override
public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
    logger.info("Reconnecting..");
}

@Override
public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnection failed.. ", e);
}

@Override
public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnecting in %d secs", seconds);
}

@Override
public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
    logger.info("Connection closed on error.");
}

@Override
public void connectionClosed() {
    logger.info("Connection closed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out the issue?  That looks like googles stock code, is that right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25999269/194894

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConnectionException when trying to connect to Openfire XMPP server from aSmack Android client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998575/connectionexception-when-trying-to-connect-to-openfire-xmpp-server-from-asmack-a)