# XMPP error using asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I'm a newbie in Android development and trying to integrate my android phone with my Openfire server installed in my machine.

I loaded the asmack jar into my libraries and wrote some code but in the logcat it throws a smack exception and cant connect.

My AsncTask code is shown below.

Note = Host is my localhost, Port is 5222 and i opened that port from control panel.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = null;
        try {
            connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE_NAME);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("dnm", "wrong config");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);


        try {
            connection.connect();

            Log.d("memo", "ok");
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("memo", "no1");
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.getCause();
            Log.d("memo", "no2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("memo", "no3");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Executed";

    }

    }
```

and the logcat is

```
11-29 13:54:07.156: D/memo(31420): no2
11-29 13:54:07.156: W/System.err(31420): org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException
11-29 13:54:07.166: W/System.err(31420):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:436)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:811)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:396)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at com.example.chattest.MainActivity$LongOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at com.example.chattest.MainActivity$LongOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-29 13:54:07.176: W/System.err(31420):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998575/connectionexception-when-trying-to-connect-to-openfire-xmpp-server-from-asmack-a

Comment: You should not use localhost . Instead use system's public IP for configuring the XMPP connection .

Comment: Doesn' work either, i used my ipv4 adress still get error. my localhost is 127.0.0.1 and my phone is connected to the same modem.

Comment: Have you checked the link on other systems too ? You should make your that your server is accessible .

Comment: I solved it by using smack4.1 alpha version but now struggling with  other problems about the smack packet reader. Thanks for your help by the way.